# Java SSL cacerts working only on local machine

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

There is a bit of code in my program that sets up a socket connection, it then writes to the remote server.

```
        //Get Socket, set timeout, and initialize I/O streams
        SSLSocket sock = null;
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("212.32.251.215");
            int port = 55540;
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) 
            SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            sock = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(host, port);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        sock.setSoTimeout(100000);
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

        //Get Message (Compress and Encrypt)
        byte[] msg = buildMsg();

        //Send message to Server
        out.write(msg);
        out.flush();
```

On my local machine everything runs smoothly but on my cloud server I am getting a familiar error – `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

I have ensured that the cert is in cacerts with `keytool -list -v -keystore /etc/pki/java/cacerts -alias myalias`.  I have also checked that this cacerts is the default truststore for my java application with `System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");` which returns `/etc/pki/java`. That being said, I have even tried `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/etc/pki/java/cacerts");` as suggested by someone who said Tomcat overlooked their default trustStore.  Also, yes this is the cacerts location for all jre versions in my server, each jre has a cacerts but it is a symbolic link to this one canonical location.

At this point I am at a loss as to why I am still get this error; any suggestions or solutions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by explicitly creating a trustStore, not relying on java to find it.

```
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(mypath), password.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(trustStore);

        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
        sslcontext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();

        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("212.32.251.215");
        int port = 55540;

        sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(host, port);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "relying on Java to find it"? There is no magic in Java. A truststore is either defined on the JVM level (cacerts) or inside an app server (e.g. Tomcat) if your app runs inside such an environment or within your app code itself. There are environment variables you can use too to set truststores...